# htaccess root and subdirectory strange behaviour

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I have two Yii apps with following tree:

```
(app v2.0)
/ 
/.htaccess
/index.php

(app v1.0)
/v1.0/ 
/v1.0/.htaccess
/v1.0/index.php
```

Root (v2.0) .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.svn
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.git
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?v2.0=%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,QSA]
```

v1.0 .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/?v1.0=%{REQUEST_URI}&file=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The idea is to get requests like `/site/index` go to `/index.php` and `/v1.0/site/index` to `/v1.0/index.php`.

I'm having quite strange result:

```
/ goes to /index.php [OK]
/site/index goes to /index.php [OK]
/v1.0/ goes to /v1.0/index.php [OK]
/v1.0/site/index goes to /index.php [??? - NOT OK]
```

`/v1.0/site/index` is passed through `/v1.0/.htaccess` (traced using params) and goes directly to `/index.php`.

[Server is running CentOS 6.5]

Not even setting `RewriteBase` solves my problem.
$_GET params `v1.0`,`v2.0` and `file` are only used to trace requests within applications.

Any guess ?